# Buy and Sell signals are differing by a candle with respect to plot

Tags: pine-script

I tried to plot a graph based on the signals which are generated from the below strategy. But I observed from the script is **signal generation points are differing by a Candle**. If anyone will know about this please help me. For reference, I attached below snapshots

[1. Buy signal snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLtoP.png)
[2. Sell signal snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNXyu.png)

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)
orderType = 0
longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
    orderType := 1

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    orderType := -1
plot(orderType,"OrderType",color.black)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true)
orderType = 0
longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
    orderType := 1

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    orderType := -1
plot(orderType,"OrderType",color.black)
```