# How to plot pine script strategy on backtested data accurately?

Tags: pine-script

[image]

I have a pine script published as a strategy but while looking at backtested data buy and sell signal shows a signal a 1-2 candle later than the actual one.

Can someone please let me know how to plot history data at an accurate candle to get a more correct summary of trades?

```
//@version=4
strategy("ABC[![enter image description here][1]][1]",calc_on_every_tick=true,overlay=false,default_qty_value=0,initial_capital=100000, currency=currency.USD,process_orders_on_close=false)
rsi_period = input(defval=9, title="RSI Period", type=input.integer)
wma_avg = input(defval=21, title="RSI WMA Period", type=input.integer)
ema_avg = input(defval=3, title="RSI EMA Period", type=input.integer)

bull_bear = input(defval=50, title="Line Value", type=input.integer)

rsi = rsi(close, rsi_period)
wma_v = wma(rsi, wma_avg)
ema_v = ema(rsi, ema_avg)


plot(wma_v, title='WMA', color=#d32f2f, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)
plot(ema_v, title="EMA", color=#00796b, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)

pl_rsi = plot(rsi, title='RSI', color=#363a45, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)

hmline = plot(50, title="Line", color=color.new(color.purple, 50),linewidth=1)

fill(pl_rsi,hmline, title = " Color Shade",color = rsi > bull_bear  ? color.new(#f44336,50) : color.new(#00bcd4,50))
//fill(pl_rsi,overbought, color = rsi < bull_sup ? color.red : na)

strategy.entry("Buy",true,1, when = ((rsi >= ema_v and rsi >= wma_v) and (ema_v >= wma_v)))
strategy.entry("Sell",false,1,when = ((rsi <= ema_v and rsi <= wma_v) and (ema_v <= wma_v)))
```

Comment: I think your problem looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60693501/buy-and-sell-signals-are-differing-by-a-candle-with-respect-to-plot/60706542#60706542

Comment: I have already tried that solution not working.

Comment: But in your script `strategy(...,process_orders_on_close=false)`. Try `strategy(...,process_orders_on_close=true)`